# How to draw a text frame on document page

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

This seems to be a stupid question. How do I draw a text frame on the actual document page in inDesign 5.5 -- NOT on a master page?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you currently have your Master page selected in the Pages pallet like this:

[image]

What you need is your standard page selected like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this isn't the problem. I definitely have the document page selected. When I draw a frame with the text tool within the document nothing happens. Also when I draw a rectangle and then click inside it with the text tool nothing happens. I can very easily draw a text frame on a master page but that is not what I want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I'm afraid I've never seen what you describe. Is there anything going with locked Layers? Or a Layer higher up than the one you're working on obscuring the text frame? Is this happening in just one document, or all InDesign documents? Is this a new problem or it has always been this way?